# Using @param for an object that is being passed through a function

Tags: javascript, parameters, jsdoc

Basically, what I need to do is use @param for an object that is being passed through to a function.

```
/** @param {String} b */
function Hello(a, { b, c }) {


}
```

I thought it would work something like this, but it doesn't.

How would I use @param on b, and c?

Comment: What do you mean "use @param"?

Comment: I just edited the post!

Comment: JSDoc is the context I was missing :). I'm curious about the answer too; not sure JSDoc can handle destructured objects like that.

Comment: Yup! I've been trying to find out how to do this for so long, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've figured it out!

```
/**
 * @param {object} param0
 * @param {Number} param0.a
*/

async function hello({ a }) {

}
```

https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html

You can read the documentation here as well!